# MySql Returning Data using Join when join does not match row

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which I am drawing data from

**ATM**

[ID][Owner][Balance][State]

**ATMAvatar**

[ATMID][Avatar][Admin][Allowed][Limited][Limit]

The current query I have is

```
SELECT ATM . * , ATMAvatar.Avatar AS User, ATMAvatar.Admin, 
    ATMAvatar.Allowed, ATMAvatar.Limited, ATMAvatar.Limit,
    (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM ATMAvatar WHERE ATMID =  '{SOME ATM ID}') AS UserCount
FROM ATM
JOIN ATMAvatar ON ATM.ID = ATMAvatar.ATMID
WHERE ATM.ID =  '{SOME ATM ID}'
AND ATMAvatar.Avatar =  '{SOME NAME}'
```

Which works well if the ATMAvatar and the ATM both have relative rows. I want to be able to convert this so that the ATM will still be selected with some default values for any of the ATMAvatar columns if the ATMAvatar row can not be found.

For Example

- ID: d7dafb52-bc31-4f38-a433-7c273b345454
- Owner: Tom Hanson
- Balance: 0
- State: 0
- User: James McCrawford (Get this from the query) as the row will not return
- Admin: 0 (Row not available so can't be admin)
- Allowed: 0 (Row not available so can't be allowed)
- Limited: 1 (Row not available so definately limit)
- Limit: 0 (Row not available so limited to $0)
- UserCount: 15

I would be happy if it just returned the rows empty and I can check that in php.

**EDIT**
My problem is I am search for James McCrawford in a selection of rows that does not contain him. I think I need to rethink the structure of the query

Comment: what is ATMID for James McCrawford? and as par UserCount it seems there are 15 records in ATMAvatar table with (ID: d7dafb52-bc31-4f38-a433-7c273b345454).

Comment: This example info is all mock info. Just an example. James McCrawford is the name of the person trying to use the ATM. There no atm in the database with that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT ATM.*,
       ATMAvatar.Avatar AS User,
       ATMAvatar.Admin,
       ATMAvatar.Allowed,
       ATMAvatar.Limited,
       ATMAvatar.Limit,
       (    SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM ATMAvatar 
            WHERE ATMID = '{SOME ATM ID}'
       ) AS UserCount
FROM ATM
JOIN ATMAvatar ON ATM.ID = ATMAvatar.ATMID 
                  AND ATMAvatar.Avatar = '{SOME NAME}'
WHERE ATM.ID = '{SOME ATM ID}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` for it, e.g.:

```
SELECT ATM . * , ATMAvatar.Avatar AS User, ATMAvatar.Admin, 
    ATMAvatar.Allowed, ATMAvatar.Limited, ATMAvatar.Limit,
    (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM ATMAvatar WHERE ATMID =  '{SOME ATM ID}') AS UserCount
FROM ATM
LEFT JOIN ATMAvatar ON ATM.ID = ATMAvatar.ATMID
WHERE ATM.ID =  '{SOME ATM ID}'
AND (ATMAvatar.Avatar =  '{SOME NAME}' OR ATMAvatar.Avatar IS NULL)
```

This would return all the records from `ATM` regardless of whether there is any matching record in `ATMAvatar`. All the `ATMAvatar` related fields in the result row would be `null` for the `ATM` record without any `ATMAvatar`.

Comment: No luck. Does it matter that ATMAvatar.Avatar is a joint primary key with ATMAvatar.ATMID

Comment: Ive realised the problem is I am selecting all the rows, then there WHERE clause is Avatar = "James McCrawford" but in the selection there is no James McCrawford

Comment: @TomHanson we have `ATMAvatar.Avatar =  '{SOME NAME}'` in the query and hence, it won't select the records which are present in `ATM` only as they won't have corresponding `ATMAvatar`.

Comment: @TomHanson I have updated the query, it should now show all the records from `ATM` table.

Comment: Still no results :(

Comment: Do you have any record for that atm id in the atm table?

Comment: Yes I did, I found the solution. Its marked as the answer. Thanks for your help :D